# Convert array of objects to objects in Vue js and php

Tags: php, json, vue.js, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

How to format this object to an array of objects?

```
[
    [
      {
        "fieldName": "4579043642",
        "message": "set number '4579043642' exists!"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "fieldName": "4579043641",
        "message": "set number '4579043641' exists!"
      }
     ],
     [
      {
        "fieldName": "4579043640",
        "message": "set number '4579043640' exists!"
      }
      ],
    ],
]
```

to this expected output as it will be trverseresed in my logic of vue js  want to get the fields in my vue js record

```
    const failed = [ {
        "fieldName": "4579043642",
        "message": "set number '4579043642' exists!"
      },
 {
        "fieldName": "4579043642",
        "message": "set number '4579043642' exists!"
      }
]
```

My PHP code returning array is:

```
 $productID = auth()->user()->product_id;
        $offers = DB::select("SELECT * FROM offers WHERE product_id = $productID");
        if(isset($offers))
        {
            $services = $offers[0]->service_id;
        }
        if(isset($services))
        {
            $services =explode(",",$services);
        }
        $totalServiceIds = array();
        foreach($services as $service)
        {
            $totalServiceIds[] = DB::select("SELECT * FROM services WHERE id = $service");

        }
return $totalServiceIds;
```

and Vue JS side is:

```
<template>
   
            <div class="box">

                <div class="card border-light"  v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">


                    <div class="card-body ">
                        <div style="height:250px">
                            <img class="card-img-top" :src="user.photos" alt="Card image cap">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card border-dark text-center" style="max-width: inherit;" >
                            <div class="card-body bg-dark text-white">

                                <p class="card-text"><b>{{ user.name }}</b></p>
                                <h5 class="card-title" v-for="offer in offers" :key="offer.id">Code: {{ offer.vouchercode }} </h5>
                                <a :href="user.link1" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Step-by-Step guide</a>
                                <a :href="user.link2" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Support Service</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-dark">
                                <a :href="user.link3" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light bg-secondary btn-block">Redeem</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
section{
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding : 10px;
    margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.card{
    background: black;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box>* {
    flex: 1 1 320px;
}
.mybox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.mybox>* {
    flex: 1 1 320px;
}
.black {
    background:black;
}
</style>

<script>
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            users: {},
            offers:{},
            user_name: this.$userId,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getUser(){
            axios.get('/getallservices')
                .then((response)=>{
                    this.users = response.data
                })
        },
        getoffers(){
            axios.get('/getalloffers')
                .then((response)=>{
                   this.offers = response.data

                })
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getUser()
        this.getoffers()
    }
}
</script>
```

Either I want a response from the backend in the expected format or I need to parse it in vUE JS IN the expected format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Flat) to accomplish this in the javascript layer as follows:

```js
    const response = [
        [
          {
            "fieldName": "4579043642",
            "message": "set number '4579043642' exists!"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "fieldName": "4579043641",
            "message": "set number '4579043641' exists!"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "fieldName": "4579043640",
            "message": "set number '4579043640' exists!"
          }
        ],
      ];

    const failed = response.flat()
    
    console.log(failed);
```

So... assuming this is your response from `/getallservices`, you would do this

```
axios.get('/getallservices')
  .then(response => response.data.flat())
  .then(console.log)
```

You would likely want to do some additional validation of the response to avoid errors.

Comment: i am using vue js and i m very new in that I have written my code above in which i need to get the value can you pease point me in that code that how will i use this array.prototype.reduce. I have updated my question

Comment: It looks like you edited the question after this.  This won't get you the desired response anymore. I'll update it.  Also not clear to me which method this is for... `getUser`?

Comment: please point me out in my code actually i am getting data frpm the php in the format [[{}],[{}]....] but i want the data in vue usage as [{},{}....]

Comment: @ArslaanMuhammadAli I updated the answer to reflect your question as it is now

Comment: thank you can you help me validations which I should use as general I am new in vue js maybe I am skipping basic validation or checks

Comment: I would personally validate that the response is actually an array before attempting to flatten it.  If you're confident that it will always be an array, you might not need to do it, but I would do something like `if(Array.isArray(response.data)) {...code here}`